# File `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: fonts, epstopdf

I meeted the problem when I tried to use a **SIAM template** ([siamart220329](https://epubs.siam.org/journal-authors#macros)).
When compiling with pdfLaTeX directly, it reports an error :

*"Package pdftex.def: File `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.\n"*

I search on Google and find `epstopdf` may be the reason and `texlive-fonts-utils` might solve my problem.
However, there are only tutorials to install it on several computer systems
**except Windows**.

A minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 \begin{document} 

\includegraphics{lexample_fig1}
 
 \end{document}
```

The error given by texworks is

```
 **!!! Error: Input filename 'lexample_fig1.eps' not allowed in**
 **restricted mode.** C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921:
 command failed with exit code 2: perl.exe
 c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl --restricted
 "--outfile=lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf" "lexample_fig1.eps"
 
 
 **! Package pdftex.def Error: File `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf'**
 **not found : using draft setting.**
 
 See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation. Type  H
 <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
 
  l.6 \includegraphics{lexample_fig1}

                                     ?
```

The complete `.log` document shows:

```
     This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.4.24)  19 DEC 2023 10:23
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count194
\scratchdimen=\dimen143
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count195
\nofMParguments=\count196
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count197
\MPscratchDim=\dimen144
\MPnumerator=\count198
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count199
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <lexample_fig1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2023-12-19 10:06:38
(epstopdf)                    size: 312532 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=lexample_fig1-eps-converte
d-to.pdf lexample_fig1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 6.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf lexample_fig1.
eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf>.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found
: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \includegraphics{lexample_fig1}
                                   
? shell escape commands
OK, entering \scrollmode...
[1

{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1314 strings out of 476025
 21714 string characters out of 5794015
 1849382 words of memory out of 5000000
 21803 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512455 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,5n,62p,197b,132s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<
c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 21567 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

---

**updates：** To find `texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl` and change `$ restricted = 1 if $ :: opt_restricted` to `$ restricted = 0 if $ :: opt_restricted` may be a solution. In this time, there will be a file named `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf` in the rooted folder .
I am warried about the danger of this change.

Comment: the warning you show is unrelated to the question in the title. If you try to input an EPS file into pdflatex, latex will call epstopdf to make a PDF file with the name you show by adding `-converted-to.pdf` to the file name. If that fails for any reason the file won't be made but before that you should have had an error from ghostscript saying why the conversion failed / Assumning you do have `lexample_fig1.eps`  but on the other hand you don't need that eps file in any real document.

Comment: the example in the zip works without any problems on windows and converts the eps. Did you actually copy the eps into your document folder?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I download the zip and directly use texworks to compile, but I just get the same error(not a warning) .

Comment: if `lexample_fig1.eps` is in the same folder as the document epstopdf must have failed to convert it, it should have left an error message on the terminal. Are you using miktex or texlive?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use Texlive.

Comment: so what happens if you open a command window and cd to the folder and type `epstopdf lexample_fig1.eps` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I type C:\Users\***\Desktop\siamart_220329>epstopdf lexample_fig1.eps,but there is no response.

Comment: Ok so now do you have a `lexample_fig1.pdf` in that folder?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I do.  I only download and compile. I don't do any other operation.

Comment: you just made that pdf, so now run the pdflatex and it should work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am really confused. The error still occurs. I try to compile the document on overleaf. There is not such an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I may find something :   !!! Error: Input filename 'lexample_fig1.eps' not allowed in restricted mode. Does this make sense?

Comment: I find texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl and change `$ restricted = 1 if $ :: opt_restricted`  to  `$ restricted = 0 if $ :: opt_restricted`. Then the compilation passes.

Comment: latex should be calling repstopdf and the default texlive texmf.cnf shoud allow repstpdf  in restricted mode (see /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf or your equivalent place) shell_escape_commands  if that is not happening then show a small complete example and show the tex log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: I mean make a small document that just does `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{lexample_fig1}\end{document}` add it to the question and also add the full log you get from pdflatex showing the failure and all the files it input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.

Comment: use code blocks not quote so line ends preserved

Comment: you have missed out the important parts of the log, it will not start  This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) 
 
  (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii

Comment: the log shows that epstopdf does successfully make the file `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf`  but apparently not where tex can find it, use the windows search in the toolbar to see if you can find where that file is, which will help debug your setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I upload the complete `.log`.  I use shell-escape-commands to jump through the error. But after searching, I don't find the file `lexample_fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf` .

Comment: Thanks. That looks really odd. The log looks completely as expected including running repstopdf to do the conversion, then on the next line it says the converted file is not there. It looks to be that your repstopdf is failing silently. The change you suggested previously would make it always use the normal epstopdf version which you say works, on a personal machine that is safe enough if you see nothing else that is wrong, it just restricts some of the options to epstopdf to stop it reading or writing files that are out of the current tex area.

Comment: if you use `pdflatex --shell-escape` then it would use the full version as well, so you could try that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your useful anwsers and so many good comments!!!! I try `pdflatex --shell-escape` but sadly it doesn't make sense.  I will go on with that change. Thanks again.